# Azure Entra Connect Cloudsync - User not synced to OnPremise Active Directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, active-directory, microsoft-entra-id

i have set up an Azure Entra Connect Cloudsync Agent on my local WinServer22 Active Directory Controller.

Groups are getting synced but not users. When syncing i get the following Message:

```
EntrySynchronizationSkip:

Result: Skipped

Description: The User 'xxxx' will be skipped due to the following reasons: 
1) This object is not assigned to the application. 
If you did not expect the object to be skipped,
assign the object to the application or change your scoping filter to allow all users
and groups to be in scope for provisioning. 
2) This object does not have required entitlement for provisioning.
If you did not expect the object to be skipped,
update provisioning scope to 'Sync all users and groups'
or assign the object to the application with entitlement of provisioning category 
3) This object did not pass a scoping filter. 
If you did not expect the object to be skipped, please review your scoping filters 
and ensure that the object passes your specified scoping criteria. 
The scope evaluation result is: {"On-prem Owned Users.dirSyncEnabled IS TRUE":false}

SkipReason: NotEffectivelyEntitled
IsActive: True
Assigned to the application: False   
IsInProvisioningScope: False
ScopeEvaluationResult: {"On-prem Owned Users.dirSyncEnabled IS TRUE":false}
```

Happens to All Entra Users.
What is the Application in the Context of "Assigned to the application: False"
and where can i set the param "On-prem Owned Users.dirSyncEnabled" if its currently false?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
If you did not expect the object to be skipped,
assign the object to the application or change your scoping filter to allow all users
and groups to be in scope for provisioning.
```

As per the above error message, `scoping filter` is not enabled for syncing users from **On-prem AD** to **Azure AD**. make sure to select all users under the scoping filter to sync **all users** and groups.

To sync users and groups from **On-Prem AD** to **Azure AD** using **Cloud Sync**, you can follow the steps below.

1. Install and connect the **Cloud Sync** agent on **On-Prem Server**.

[image]

2. After completing the agent configuration, verify the agent status.

[image]

3. To synchronize all users and groups to `Azure AD`, choose the **All users** option.

[image]

4. Restart the **sync** once you select the scoping filters

[image]

5. The users and groups are synced to **Azured Ad** successfully.

[image]

[image]

If **Dirsync** is disabled, you may enable **Dirsync** using below command.

```
Install-Module MSOnline
Set-MsolDirSyncEnabled -EnableDirsync $True
```

[image]

Reference:   [Create a new configuration for Microsoft Entra Cloud Sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/hybrid/cloud-sync/how-to-configure)

[Turn on directory synchronization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/set-msoldirsyncenabled?view=azureadps-1.0#example-1-turn-on-directory-synchronization)

Comment: ok this works for existing local AD owned users.

i created new users in office365 and want to sync them down to the local AD for RDP usage and they are owned by entra. any idea here? 
still the same problem with those users

Or did it get it wrong and all users need to be first setup via the local ad? i thought this is the goal of the Microsoft Entra ID to AD sync to create users via cloud and use them locally too.